# Config balance haproxy with use tags in header on request

Tags: haproxy

I have a question about config balance with use haproxy.
I want config balance with use header tags on requests. 
I have 2 tag - kasko, osago and default_backend.
How I can config balance for tags
- if I have one tag in header request - balance backend osago,
 
- if second tag - balance backend kasko, 
- if don't have tag - use default backend?

I tried use hdr_val how wrote on this instructions
 https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/9-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/acls/ 
and this
 
https://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/08/neo4j-and-haproxy-some-best-practices-and-tricks/ 
but it don't work.

```
 frontend web_80
    bind *:80
    mode http
    option httplog
    acl acl_osago hdr_val(Calculation-Type:OSAGO) eq 1
    acl acl_kasko hdr_val(Calculation-Type:KASKO) eq 1
    use_backend osago if acl_osago
    use_backend kasko if acl_kasko
    default_backend web_80

backend osago 
    mode http
    server server5_7003 server5:7003 check port 7001

backend kasko
    mode http
    server server6_7003 server6:7003 check port 7001

backend web_80
    mode http
    balance leastconn
    option httpchk GET /ibss-checker/threads/info/queue-length
    http-check expect rstring ^(0?[0-9]?[0-9]|1[0-1][0-9])$
    server server1_7003 server1:7003 check port 7001
    server server2_7003 server2:7003 check port 7001
    server server3_7003 server3:7003 check port 7001
    server server4_7003 server4:7003 check port 7001
```

Answer (score 0):

Helped dev recompiling programm and this config

```
acl acl_osago hdr_val(Calculation-Type:OSAGO) eq 1
```

worked